# Autocomplete support for custom JS library in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My company has a JS library and wants to create autocomplete support in VSCode. For example if user writes `xxXor.` all possible library functions for the instance should show up, like `xxXor.bit`, etc

Is there a template for such a VScode extension?

Answer (score 0):

From what i know this should be accomplished simply by importing the package. It may take some time for VSCode to read/process the entire library, but it does that automatically.

[You can check this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) for more info about this feature.